# Get the name of the variable of the button

Tags: java, swing, variables, jbutton

I work on a project with git where encoding may be different for several machines.

If I set this :

```
private JButton translationButton1 = new JButton("←");
translationButton1.addActionListener(this);
```

Then I set the listener :

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

I know it's possible to get the "←" by using `e.getActionCommand()` but I'm afraid that if somebody who haven't the same encoding as me (Cp1252 for example), I'm not sure to get "←".

It is possible to get the name of the button in the `actionPerformed method` (`if(???.equals("translationButton1")`) ? (I don't want to use an `anonymous inner type` because I have several actionListener to set)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can set an action command:

```
translationButton1.setActionCommand("translationButton1");
```

And then check for the command:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getActionCommand.equals("translationButton1") {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: this is reason for annonymous whatever, then there any issue, nor I can't found Encoding (excluding east and south Asia)

Answer (score 1):

You can get `encoding` on user's computer by `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`

So for you the code should look like:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String encoding =System.getProperty("file.encoding");
    if (encoding.equals("UTF-8"))
       // do something
    else if (encoding.equals("Cp1252"))
       // do something else
    // else if (encoding.equals("someEncoding"))
       do something else yet
    }
```

Nevertheless, I would recommend you also the approach, that @whiskeyspider has desribed here...it's cleaner practice for this case..

Comment: Yes, it's cleaner than considering all encoding that may I trouble with

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to get the name of the button..?

1 button might be assigned to 3 different attribute names or none. So no, it is not possible to get 'the' variable name.